# Start my Location Activity at fixed time interval in android

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

```
public class LocUpdator extends Activity implements LocationListener {

 private TextView latituteField;
  private TextView longitudeField;
  private LocationManager locationManager;
  private LocationManager service;
  private String provider;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);


    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
    // default
    service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean enabled = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // Check if enabled and if not send user to the GSP settings
            // Better solution would be to display a dialog and suggesting to 
            // go to the settings
            if (!enabled) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
              startActivity(intent);
            } 
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    //criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    //criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
      System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
      Toast.makeText(this, "Provider " + provider + " has been selected." ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {
      latituteField.setText("Is GPS ON ?");
      longitudeField.setText("Sorry! No GPS");
    }
  }

  /* Request updates at startup */
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
  }

  /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
    double lng = (double) (location.getLongitude());
    //Http Post method to send data to srver Php document
    Toast.makeText(this, "Transfered location: "+lat+" "+lng ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Currently using " + provider + " technology." ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    //longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
  }

  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Toast.makeText(this, "Location Change Notification !!" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


  }

  @Override
  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }

  @Override
  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

I want this activity of mine to  be started at a fixed interval of time , I tried the Alarm Manager and BroadcastReciever but ... I cannot Find Any way to start this from the broadcast receiver...

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Toast.makeText(context, "Location Cordinates Updating!!!!.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Toast.makeText(context, "Current Location :",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, LocUpdator.class);
    context.startActivity(startIntent);
    startIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Above is the BroadcastReciever

The AlarmActivity is below

public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void startAlert(View view) {
    //EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time);
    int i = 20;//Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
    //int i= 10;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+ (i * 1000), pendingIntent);
    //long timerInterval= i*1000;
    //alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), timerInterval, pendingIntent); 
    //finish();  
    Toast.makeText(this, "DB Update Interval set as " + i + " seconds",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Please Help Me out here :-)

---

The log Cat Error is below

```
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{twin.geolocator/twin.geolocator.insideActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider==null
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider==null
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at android.location.LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.java:1153)
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at twin.geolocator.insideActivity.onCreate(insideActivity.java:32)
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
09-10 09:50:15.368: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  ... 11 more
```

---

```
public class insideActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria c = new Criteria();
    c.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    c.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    c.setBearingRequired(false);
    c.setSpeedRequired(false);
    c.setCostAllowed(true);
    c.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(c,true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
      System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
      onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {
      Log.d("Location not available", "inside");
      Log.d("Location not available", "inside ");
    }
    Log.d("Inside onCreate", "1");
  }


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("Inside onLocationChanged", "2");


}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("Inside onProviderDisabled", "3");

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("Inside onProviderEnabled", "4");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg1, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("onStatusChanged", "");
}

}
```

Comment: try to make a custom broadcast intent and then broadcast your custom intent using a delay of whatever you want.... and put the put the location activity in the onReceive() of braodcast receiver class!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read my comment and then use this for delay...

For a repeating task:

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, after, interval);
```

For a single run of a task:

```
new Timer().schedule(task, after);
```

task being the method to be executed
after the time to initial execution
(interval the time for repeating the execution)

Comment: Thankyou Aditya , I will try afresh with a new custom broadcast intent. And as you said a timer also :-) i will try that and get back soon :-)

Comment: But Aditya , i cannot start the activity from within the receiver , it is crashing :-( please help , something might be wrong with manifesto permissions and < receiver > ?

Comment: I reworked the code will post the activity code again , The solution you suggested wa perfect , the activty started when i commented out the GPS code section. But with GPS section the NULLPOINTER error is popping up :-( i think something is wrong with the variable "provider".

Comment: ok show me the code where it got null pointer... and yes mark the answer helpful if you found the answer to the question you posted!

Comment: i solved it , it was the manifest :-( i forgot to give the permissions to use the location services :-) silly me :-) Thanks alot Aditya for your time :-) See you again :-)